# animationClip.SampleAnimation() does not result in visible changes

Tags: unity, c#

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
public class AnimatedGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float extentPlayed;

    public AnimationClip Clip;
    public GameObject AnimationTarget;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (this.extentPlayed >= 1f)
        {
            return;
        } 

        Debug.Log(this.extentPlayed);

        this.Clip.SampleAnimation(this.AnimationTarget, extentPlayed * this.Clip.length);
        this.extentPlayed += 0.005f;
    }
}
```

In the Unity Editor, the game object assigned to `AnimationTarget` contains the animator component controlled by the controller that uses `Clip`.

However, when I start the game, even though I can see that `this.extentPlayed` is being incremented every frame, no animation is taking place that I can see.

I am aware that what I am currently trying to do in the `Update()` method can be achieved by calling `SetBool(string name, bool value)` on the animator, but the purpose of writing the `Update()` method this way is to gain familiarity with how the `SampleAnimation()` method works, so that I can perform more complicated manipulations when necessary.

What changes should I make for the animation to take place?

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this in case it is relevant to someone:

You can't use SampleAnimation for sampling a sub-object of an animation. You have to sample the whole object (the parent object).

For example: If you got a character waving animation, you can't sample just the hand. You need to sample the whole character.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem where a GameObject would not animate via `SampleAnimation()` in the player.  To solve it, I:

1. made sure an `Animator` referencing an `Animation Controller` was attached to the GameObject and
2. disabled the `Animator` component.